# Tailwind CSS resize column width

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I'm trying, just for exercise, to make a simple card that looks like a Whatsapp chat preview. I'm using tailwind css and a grid layout to achieve it.
Here is my code:

```
<div class="grid grid-cols-4 w-96 bg-zinc-800 rounded-md">
<div class="shrink-0 p-3 border-red-800 max-w-fit h-20 border">
    <img src="./assets/placeholder.png" alt="" class="max-h-full rounded-full">
</div>
<div class="p-3 col-span-2 font-helvetica border-red-800 border">
    <h1 class="text-neutral-100">Andrea Militano</h1>
    <div class="flex text-neutral-400">
        <fa-icon [icon]="faCheck" class=""></fa-icon>
        <fa-icon [icon]="faCheck" class="-translate-x-2"></fa-icon>
        <p class="text-sm truncate -translate-x-1">Contenuto del messaggio, Contenuto del messaggio, Contenuto del messaggio</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="border-red-800 justify-self-end p-3 border">
    <p class="text-neutral-400 text-sm">21.23</p>
</div>
```

and this is the result:
[image: Grid Layout]

How can I to to let the second column to grab all the space left from the other two columns?
I thought that with a flex layout it was easier, but I struggle to make the last div end within the parent div border.
This is the flex variant:

```
<div class="flex w-96 bg-zinc-800 rounded-md">
<div class="shrink-0 p-3 border-red-800 max-w-fit h-20 border">
    <img src="./assets/placeholder.png" alt="" class="max-h-full rounded-full">
</div>
<div class="p-3 font-helvetica border-red-800 border max-w-[65%]">
    <h1 class="text-neutral-100">Andrea Militano</h1>
        <div class="flex text-neutral-400">
            <fa-icon [icon]="faCheck" class=""></fa-icon>
            <fa-icon [icon]="faCheck" class="-translate-x-2"></fa-icon>
            <p class="text-sm truncate">Message content</p>
        </div>
</div>
<div class="border-red-800 p-3 border">
    <p class="text-neutral-400 text-sm">21.23</p>
</div>
```

With the following result:

[image: Flex Layout]

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do so by adding `flex-1` to fill the empty space and adding `overflow-hidden` to fix text overflow from the parent.

```html
<div class="flex w-96 gap-3 rounded-md bg-zinc-800">
  <div class="h-20 max-w-fit shrink-0 border border-red-800 p-3">
    <img src="https://i.pravatar.cc/150?img=3" alt="" class="max-h-full rounded-full" />
  </div>
  <div class="flex-1 font-helvetica border border-red-800 p-3 overflow-hidden">
    <h1 class="text-neutral-100">Andrea Militano</h1>
    <div class="flex text-neutral-400">
      <fa-icon [icon]="faCheck" class=""></fa-icon>
      <fa-icon [icon]="faCheck" class="-translate-x-2"></fa-icon>
      <p class="truncate text-wrap text-sm">Message content</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="border border-red-800 p-3">
    <p class="text-sm text-neutral-400">21.23</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Also, you have to remove `max-w-[65%]` to make sure that it will always take the remaining space

Comment: Yes, I think so

Comment: The only problem is that if I put more text inside of my <p>, it will overflow from the parent

Comment: You can add `text-wrap` in the `<p>` class to wrap the text in a new line

Comment: Yes but I just want to see one line and then the "..." as it was a message preview

Comment: add `overflow-hidden` to the same part of class `flex-1`

Comment: Yesss this finally works!